# "Замітки на полях" чи "замітки на берегах"?

Tags: вибір-слова

Мова йдеться про записи обабіч тексту в книзі, зроблені читачем, тобто [*маргіналії*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%97).

"*Замітки на берегах*" (а також "*завваги на берегах*") в інтернетах як словосполучення майже не знаходиться, на відміну від "*замітки на полях*".

СУМ-11 подає [*поля*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pole)<sup>7</sup>:

> Смужка уздовж краю аркуша паперу, яка залишається чистою при писанні або друкуванні; берег.

і [*берег*](http://sum.in.ua/s/beregh)<sup>4</sup>:

> Краї книжки, зшитка, аркуша і т. ін.; поля.

як взаємозамінні.

То чи є кращий варіянт з-поміж них, чи можна вживати обидва?

Comment: Береги у цьому контексті має присмак поетичності, романтизму, вишуканості, а поля якось буденно.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Борис Антоненко-Давидович у праці ["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/polya-berehy-krayi-krysy) відповідає так:

> «На полях книжки було багато дрібно писаних олівцем нотаток», — читаємо в одному сучасному оповіданні. Чому написано «на полях», а не на берегах? Адже **білі краї книжки чи зошита звались і звуться по-українському береги**: «Одну по одній перегортав сторінки. Плями на берегах таїли в собі приємні і неприємні згадки» (Н. Рибак); «Книжка з золотими берегами» (Словник Б. Грінченка).

Але, як ви зазначили в питанні, СУМ вважає обидва варіанти нормативними. [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3940&page=150) цього, на жаль, не збирається змінювати.

Але якщо звернути увагу на приклади, то можемо сміливо припустити, що таке значення слова "поля" з'явилося за радянських часів. (приклади на "береги" в такому значенні є зі словника Грінченка, Івана Франка й Натана Рибака 1953 року, а на "поля" - лише Натан Рибак 1960 і Наука і життя).

Відповідно, варіант "береги" питоміший, проте обидва варіанти наразі є нормативними.

**Оновлення**: як зазначив YellowSky, також [словники](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on) дають варіант *"краї"*.
І припущення про те, що слово *"поле"* в цьому значенні з'явилося за радянських часів може бути хибним: Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка) передає російське поле як «2. бе́рег, край, по́ле (в книжцї або в рукопису)».
Але щоб переконатися в цьому, потрібні додаткові дослідження: якщо після 1898 року немає жодних згадок такого використання, то, можливо, це значення вийшло з ужитку й повернулося лише за радянських часів.